# GitHUb pull request default title

Tags: github, version-control, pull-request

When I create a PR it's title and body are already filled, in case of main with last commit title and body, and if I create PR to other branch it paste my branch's name as a title.
Do somebody know where/how can I manage this default PR titles?

Comment: I snipped the [tag:git] tag as Git's only contribution here is to store commits. Everything else is up to GitHub itself.

Answer (score 2):

GitHub doesn't offer a way to manage default PR titles or messages.  In general, there aren't many sane things that could be filled in as a title or PR message.  For example, you wouldn't always want to use the same title for a PR, because that would make it difficult for others to reason about your change.

If the default title or message don't suit you, you can just replace them with the values you'd like.  For example, I often replace the body with a more nicely formatted version of one of my commit messages, and I'll often change the title to something more descriptive (and properly capitalized).  It's fully expected that you'll need to do some editing here; the goal is to just make it so that sometimes, you need to do less.

Comment: I would just add that this is not always true, sometimes it can help to have by default a word or number for integrations looking for this as opposed to have to add them manually after thhe fact. It seems reasonable that I would be able to pick a template if I so desired.